# Update Python Variables via Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix, python-2.7, sh

I have a shell script that executes a two python scripts in order.  After the shell script has executes, I need to manually go into the python script and update two variables.  I'm hoping to automate this portion in the shell script, but am not exactly sure where to start.

Basically, I'm wondering if I can pass (and increment on each run) shell variables into a Python script.

Shell

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Download Data"
python /Download.py

wait

echo "Process Data"
python /Process.py
```

Python Download

```
import downloadFunction
downloadFunction.donwload('2014-03-28')
```

Python Process

```
import processData
processData.process(data)
```

Essentially, I want to increment the date via the shell script let's say 5 times.

So In the Python Script define the date variable.

Python Download

```
import downloadFunction
date = '2014-03-28'
downloadFunction.donwload(date)
```

Then each time the shell script runs the Download.py and Process.py, I want it to add a day to the date - for let's say five days.  I'm not sure where to start on this.

Comment: Is the date always going to be the current date, or is it completely unrelated?

Comment: Completely unrelated.  It's a string in the Python script.

Comment: You could start by using `grep` to extract the date from the file.  Use `date` to increment it.  Use `sed` to store it in a file.  Execute!

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass a date to the script as an argument, not edit a hard-coded value.

In `Download.py`:

```
import downloadFunction
date = sys.argv[1]
downloadFunction.donwload(date)
```

Then in your shell script, something like

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Download Data"
for d in 2014-03-28 2014-03-29 2014-03-30 2014-03-31 2014-04-01; do
    python /Download.py "$d"
done

# No need to call wait here

echo "Process Data"
python /Process.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Just beat me to the punch.  Figured I share my solution.  Basically, the same as

```
#!/bin/sh

declare -a arr=("2014-04-01")

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    echo "Download Data"
    export i
    python Download.py

    echo "Process Data"
    python /Process.py

done
```

Where download.py

```
import downloadFunction
import os
x = os.environ['i']

downloadFunction(x)
```